# Capybara/Ruby dropdown values selection

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

Drop-down values of month selection while registration of a new account in google.

I need to select the value December after I click on the the month field.
This I need in *capybara/ruby*.
I have used the below code to search month drop-down and click it.

```
find("#BirthMonth").click
```

Now the values in drop-down appear in my result but I need to know how to select them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
find('#BirthMonth').select(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the select is a real <select> element then

```
select('December', from: 'BirthMonth')
```

Should do what you want without worrying about the find and click. If it's a select replacement built from div, ul, li, etc then we'd need you to post an hetml sample